# How to find average of Peak values in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, google-sheets-formula

I have excel sheet in which Column B contains data values,
Column C contains Peak values which obtained from given formula

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND((B8-B9)/B9<0,(B9-B10)/B10>=0),B9,""),"")
```

and F1 is target value which is average of peak values retrieved in Column C.

```
=AVERAGE(C2:C60)
```

[image: Excel Sheet]

My question is, is there any way to calculate target value (i.e. Average of Peak Values) without retrieving the peak values in additional column?

Notes:

1. the formula should also work on google sheets
2. no provision to use VBA/Scripts features
3. formula/method to obtain peaks can be updated, if required, but results should be the same

Sample Excel file:
[Sample Excel File (Google Drive Download Link) Office 2019](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_wWFBgzlmouGoND0KCOVOhZtRbyl-WLW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Paste the formula in the post.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: If it is excel, remove the tag google-sheets-formula.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data in a copyable way. This would be much easier than to guess, what could be working in your case.

Comment: Sample provided, please.

Comment: I adapted the ranges to your sample and it works as expected. Both values, from my function and from the `AVERAGE`, are the same.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((B2:B61-B3:B62)/B3:B62<0)*((B3:B62-B4:B63)/B4:B63>=0)*(B3:B62))/SUMPRODUCT(((B2:B61-B3:B62)/B3:B62<0)*((B3:B62-B4:B63)/B4:B63>=0))
```

I have just integrated your conditions into `SUMPRODUCT`s. Take care with the offset of the ranges, when adapting to your data.

[image]